# Active Storage and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I set up Active Storage to use Amazon AWS S3.  I have it all set up.  When I upload an image it shows up in my AWS bucket just fine.  The problem I am having is that when I display the image via `<img src="<%= url_for(current_user.avatar) %>">` I get a broken image link.

Now what I get in inspect on the page is:
`<img src="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--15a99e4747fa8cdc7cd4bacf3de460d6ce4066de/AlanAlda.png">`

but what I get in the rails console is:
`Redirected to https://hpotter.s3.amazonaws.com/kf3kzqzj54am38jjd7k3jfux4q3d?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D%22AlanAlda.png%22%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27AlanAlda.png&response-content-type=image%2Fpng&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAQQXYWGXDLPMYBQGW%2F20191130%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20191130T011149Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=4c8fff1e88e6b9647d40f73e499edba2078f7a6d9f9c2fb0870477f2a62e9bc7
Completed 302 Found in 141ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms | Allocations: 182103)`

So It's connecting to the right image link but it's the link is different in the actual web browser.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value '/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--15a99e4747fa8cdc7cd4bacf3de460d6ce4066de/AlanAlda.png"' is Base64 encoded.

Did you setup cors correctly
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30723

Comment: Have you setup cors correctly on your s3 bucket?  Can you share the tutorial that you are following

Comment: Edited the answer above, check if you have the correct host header.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.  The information you posted is about having problems uploading.  I don't have any problems uploading, it uploads just fine.  My problem is getting the uploaded image to display.

Comment: If you try to access the url that you get in the rail console directly on the browser, do you see the image

Comment: no.  But I do see the image in my AWS bucket. That's what I'm confused about.  I used a form to upload the image, and the image is there.  So that part worked. I'm just not getting why `<img src="<%= url_for(current_user.avatar) %>">`  doesan't display the image.

Comment: How about the redirected url. Is it working on the browser

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. Can you try this for me. Replace `<%= jmage_tag(current_user.avatar) %>` instead of `<img src="<%= url_for(current_user.avatar)`

Comment: `image_tag(current_user.avator)

Comment: Thank you for helping.  I ended up starting a new project and used the same setup as before and this time it worked.  So I'm still not sure what I missed but it works now.